# Instance method '-addOperation:waitUntilFinished:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

is addOperation:waitUntilFinished available only for iOS 4.3 and above?
Why do I get this warning, am I missing out on something?

Even tough I get this warning message my app works and with it?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html

Edited with some code:

My HttpRequestWrapper Operation class:
in .h:

```
@interface HttpRequestWrapper : NSOperation
```

in .m

```
+ (id)httpRequestWrapper:(NSString *)xmlString withUser : (NSString *) user  andPassword: (NSString *) password 
{
    HttpRequestWrapper * operation = [[self alloc] initWithString:xmlString andUser: user andPass: password];
    //return [operation autorelease];
    return operation;
}

- (id)initWithString: (NSString*) xmlString andUser: (NSString* )user andPass: (NSString *) pass
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil)
        return nil;

    _urlPart = [xmlString copy];
    _userString = [user copy];
    _passString = [pass copy];
    _isExecuting = NO;
    _isFinished = NO;

    [self main];

    return self;
}
```

My caller line is like this:

```
 httpRequestWrapper  = [HttpRequestWrapper httpRequestWrapper:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/list?xsl="] withUser:NULL andPassword: NULL];
[appDelegate.operationQueue addOperation:httpRequestWrapper waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

Thanks for the help.

Lily

Comment: Let's see your code.  The method is available in iOS 4.0 +

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can assume that warning can be caused by your call `[self main];`. Note: the `main` method is called inside operation queue. I cannot see the reason to call it by yourself.

Or. I see the problem. There is no call like this:

```
[appDelegate.operationQueue addOperation:httpRequestWrapper waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

See reference more close:

```
- (void)addOperations:(NSArray *)ops waitUntilFinished:(BOOL)wait
```

you should pass the array of operations.

Fix to:

```
NSArray *opsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:httpRequestWrapper];
[appDelegate.operationQueue addOperations:opsArray waitUntilFinished:YES];
```

The third - check if `appDelegate.operationQueue` is not `nil`, i.e. if you created `operationQueue` before.

Comment: I added [self main] caller, cos for some reason - (void) start or - (void) main in the NSOperation class HttpRequestWrapper were not called automatically. If you can tell me why this could be would be great. As for appDelegate.operationQueue I call it from there cos I create the NSOperationQueue instance in the appDelegate and I want to have only one OperationQueue all over the app, that I can access it from every view.

Comment: Fix 2 errors in your code, as I said: 1) fix addOperations call; 2) remove [self main]; Then please let me know if all Ok.

Comment: Aha I see my error, I have to create an array of operations. It says addOperations not addOperation. Ok I see my error. So basically you can't add a single operation and wait until is finished. It is a group (array of operations) that you wait them to be finished.

Comment: If I remove [self main] then the - (void) start or - (void) main they don't get called at all in the operation class. That is why I have them.

Comment: That is what I said before. Great!

Comment: Do you have -(void) start - reimplemented or -(void)main ?

Comment: Yeah I tried to reimplement - (void) start only and it does not lunch by itself. Even if I have - (void) main implemented as well, so that is why I lunch them with [self main]. I read the NSOperation documentation but I still don't get if they should lunch automatically and do I need both or one of them and when exactly do I use them.

Comment: You need one of them. I think -(void)main would be enough. -(void)start is used to async thread start. And -Yes - -(void)main sould be invoked by NSOperationQueue.

Comment: Unfortunately even just with - (void) main is not invoked automatically. I created my code according to one example but it is still not working as it should be